# Linux kernel programming: can't include header file

Tags: linux, gcc, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

I am new in programming kernel linux , I'm trying to program in the linux kernel a function to find the number of processors in the system and I find this.

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/mmzone.h>
void main(void){
 information_nodos();
}
long information_nodos(){
 printk(KERN_WARNING,first_online_pgdat());
}
```

The error is :

```
fatal error : linux/mmzone.h : no such file or directory
```

I know you can not mix normal C libraries, the kernel, as they are independent, but why is this error happens?

Comment: You're likely missing some gcc parameters like -I.

Comment: Where did you put this function ? Which file have you modified ?

Comment: But is necesary add -I , -I in gcc is solo for files.a not for files.h , this files can run whit include no?

Comment: -I is for the include path. Check man gcc.

Comment: How exactly are you compiling this code? Is this part of a kernel module or not?

Comment: i create application for syscall for kernel

Comment: Are you compiling this along with your kernel? Or perhaps as a distinct kernel module ... Is your `linux/mmzone.h` in your kernel source tree? If you're compiling this as a user space linux application you should rather look for the header in `/usr/include/linux/mmzone.h` or in your gcc -I included path.

Comment: What I'm doing is making a copy program within Linux kernel, then compile it (so it did not affect the kernel itself). But also I think it would have to ignore the include.
But I will try as you mention me.

Comment: I try.

gcc -Wall -I ~/linux/include/linux/ ~/linux/mm/ exer2.c -o exer2

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that what you are trying to do is use some [kernel header file](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/mmzone.h) into a user space program.
There is some specialized Linux kernel API to implement a kernel module, if that's what you're trying to do - see the [LDD3](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/) book. For user space programs you should stick to what the C library offers.